# How can i do the same in object oriented programming with better coding?

Tags: python, api

How can i do the same in object oriented programming with better coding? Maybe by creating a class and reuse the same code? Right now what i have is more like a script not resuable code

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://sandbox.esignlive.com/api/packages"

payload = json.dumps({"documents":[{"id":"sample-contract","name":"Test Document"}],"status":"SENT","type":"PACKAGE","roles":[{"type":"SIGNER","id":"Signer1","signers":[{"email":"signer@example.com","firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","id":"Signer1"}],"name":"Signer1"}],"name":"Example Package"})

file = open('doc1.pdf', 'rb')

files = {
     'payload': payload,
     'file': file
}

headers = {
    'authorization': "Basic **********",
    'accept': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)

# create a new approval
url = "https://sandbox.esignlive.com/api/packages/" + str(response.text[1]) + "/documents/sample-contract/approvals"
requests.post(url, headers=headers)

# Create a new field with an auto-generated name
url = "https://sandbox.e-signlive.com/api/user/customfields"
requests.post(url, headers=headers)

# get and display signing url
url = "https://sandbox.e-signlive.com/api/packages/"+response.text+"/roles/Signer1/signingUrl"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: I see no benefit to defining classes for this.

Comment: but if the script keeps increasing then i will need it?

Comment: That depends on how the script grows. Object-oriented design is only one possible tool; it doesn't help everywhere.

Comment: lets say i have 100 more requests?

Comment: You'll need to start using loops and functions, and you may want to move hardcoded data into a separate data file or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your code to be re-usable, you just need to use some functions. Weather or not you put those functions inside of a class is all a matter of personal taste. The following is how you would do so.

```
import requests
import json

class Document(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """ Setup the variables on the object as soon as one is created """
        self.url = "https://sandbox.esignlive.com/api/packages"
        self.headers = {
            'authorization': "Basic **********",
            'accept': "application/json"
            }

    def create_new_approval(self, doc):
        """create a new approval """
        #you'll probably want to change this function to accept additional items other than self and doc that you can place inside of the payload. I'll leave that up to you to do.

        payload = json.dumps({"documents":[{"id":"sample-contract","name":"Test Document"}],"status":"SENT","type":"PACKAGE","roles":[{"type":"SIGNER","id":"Signer1","signers":[{"email":"signer@example.com","firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","id":"Signer1"}],"name":"Signer1"}],"name":"Example Package"})

        file = open(doc, 'rb')

        files = {
             'payload': payload,
             'file': file
        }

        response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=self.headers)

        url = "https://sandbox.esignlive.com/api/packages/" + str(response.text[1]) + "/documents/sample-contract/approvals"
        response = requests.post(self.url, headers=self.headers)

        #You'll want to do something like this each time you talk to esign in case esign gives back an error
        if not reponse:
            raise Exception("Failed to create an approval")

        return response.text

    def add_field(self):
        """Create a new field with an auto-generated name """
        url = "https://sandbox.e-signlive.com/api/user/customfields"
        requests.post(self.url, headers=self.headers)

    def get_signing_url(self, give_this_a_good_name):
        """ get the signing url """
        url = "https://sandbox.e-signlive.com/api/packages/"+give_this_a_good_name+"/roles/Signer1/signingUrl"
        response = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers)
        return response

    def display_signing_url(self):
        """ display signing url """
        print(self.get_signing_url())

# You would then use your Document object like this.
doc = Document('doc1.pdf')
doc_name_maybe = doc.add_field()
doc.display_signing_url(doc_name_maybe)
```

There may be some flaws with the class, but let me know in the comments if anything doesn't work. I don't know how esign works, but this should give you a good place to start.